# Why not send a 301 redirect when forcing HTTPS by mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, https, http-status-code-301

There are a lots of example in the net which suggest to force HTTPS. E.g:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I have nowhere found any example which uses a `301 Moved Permanently`redirect. Why not?
Wouldn't this avoid further requests to the HTTP site? And Google search results pointing to the HTTP site?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why is this used by nobody? Or did I just overlooked somebody who uses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[R]` flag will force an external redirect, the default status being 302 (temporarily relocated). AFAIK, you can set it to 301 by using `[R=302,L]`

I do not know why you wouldn't use 301 instead of 302 in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, why do people not proposing it? According to various sources, 302 redirects should be avoided if the new location is permanent (as it is in this case).

Comment: I agree, 301 makes more sense here.